# Swift: Enviar datos(arreglo, diccionario) al servidor

Tags: swift

Estoy intentando enviar un diccionario al servidor pero no logro que el servidor reciba los datos:

```
func testSendData(){
    let id_user = 78
    let projects = [1,2,5]
    let data:[String:Any] = ["id_user": id_user, "projects":projects]
        
    guard let serialization = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted) else{
            print("JSON serialitation error")
            return
    }
        
    let url = URL(string: "https://mipagina.com/api/pagina.php")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: serialization) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print ("error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
            let isError = json["error"] as! Int
            if isError == 0{
                print(json["message"]!)
            }else{
                print(json["message"]!)
            }
        }catch{print("JSON error")}
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Este es el código completo de la función de prueba, no se si estoy codificando mal los datos, intente también con esta otra función:

```
guard let serialization = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted) else{
    print("JSON serialitation error")
    return
}
guard let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(serialization) else{
    print("JSON encoded error")
    return
}
```

Use el JSONEncoder() sobre los datos serializados porque si lo uso sobre el diccionario me manda un error que no es completible con el tipo Any.

También cambie la tarea en lugar de usar uploadTask() use dataTask(), tanto con datos serializados como con JSONEncoder():

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpBody = serialization
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
.
.
.
}
```

El servidor me responde con datos nulos, del lado del servidor tengo simplemente un echo con los datos que recibo:

```
$id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
echo json_encode(['error'=> 0, 'message'=> $id_user]);
```

¿Que otra forma puedo intentar o que me esta faltando a la hora de convertir los datos?

Comment: La conversión del diccionario a json si funciona con tu código. Qué error tienes? El `id_user` está dentro del json, porqué usas `$_POST['id_user'];`?

Comment: Esto me responde el servidor:
`['error': 0, 'message': <null>]` las conversiones funcionan bien, uso un simple print() y los datos están allí. uso $_POST porque es el que he usado en todos los proyectos web, pensé que es el único que se usaba para este propósito de recibir datos por el método post.

Comment: En php debes recorrer el json que recibes e ir buscando los nodos. Así puedes tener acceso a los valores.